# Opening Excel Files From Sharepoint using Google Chrome

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome-extensions

When I attempt to open an excel file from Sharepoint using Google Chrome, I get an error message: that there is an unsupported feature and would I like to open in Excel.  If you say yes, then I get another error saying I must have excel and my browser must be configured to open directly from excel in the browser ???   Anyone seen this before ?

Comment: SharePoint version you are using?

Answer (score 4):

Installing the Chrome extension [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) did the job for me.

It has the ability to auto-detect URLs so whenever I browse to our SharePoint it emulates Internet Explorer. Finally I can open Office documents directly from Chrome.

Comment: Note: IE Tab is windows only.

Answer (score 0):

This article provides details on browser support for SharePoint 2010 Browser Support  Chrome is now supported. Even some MS browsers have limitations. Firefox is also listed as supported.

There are a number of comments on Chrome on various MS sites and others that some features work but not fully supported.  For example [Cross Browser suport](http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2009/12/sharepoint-2010-cross-browser.html)  or [MSDN discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/1f94ac6f-1913-4367-9b4c-c2c4290f24ee/)

Comment: There is a glitch in the MS TechNet Browser Support page which does not render the product version selector correctly. A valid URL for the SharePoint 2010 page version is http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx.